# Multiple files upload as zip file

Tags: php

I have a site which allows users to upload multiple files. But it uploads multiple files to a folder now i want to zip and be stored. Is it possible without using plugins? I found on net to use plugins but is it possible using php and javascript?

Here is my code for the multiple file upload :

```
$result = '';   
$zipfilename=null;   
$file = $_FILES['zipfile'];
if(empty($zipfilename))
    $zipfilename = $file['name'];
if ($file['size'] > 0) 
{
    $dir = PROBLEMZIPS."/".sprintf("%05d",$KBID)."/";
    $tmpName = $file['tmp_name'];
    $dirName = $dir;
    $fileName = $zipfilename;
    if (!is_dir($dirName)) 
    { 
        mkdir($dirName, 0777); 
    } 
    $destFile = $dirName . strtolower($fileName);
    foreach ($_FILES["zipfile"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
        if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            $name = $_FILES["zipfile"]["name"][$key];
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["zipfile"]["tmp_name"][$key], $dirName ."/". $_FILES['zipfile']['name'][$key]);       
            $zipz[] = $name;
            $result = implode(' , ', $zipz);
        }   
    }
    $changesForEveryone[] = "Zip File Uploaded: " . $result;
    $extraMsg .= "<br>Zip File Uploaded: " . $result."<br>";
} 
else 
{
    $result = false;
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php

Comment: What is wrong with plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me :

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$file = Array();
$zip->open('zip/try.zip',  ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach($_FILES['zipfile']['name'] as $file) {
echo $file;
$zip->addFile($file);
echo "<br/>";
}
$zip->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

her is a method to zip upload files

```
    function zipFile($fileName,$folder,$u) {
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $zip->open($folder.'/'.$fileName.".rar", ZipArchive::CREATE);
    $zip->addFile($u,$fileName);
    $zip->close();
    return true;
}

$tmpFile = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$file = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
zipFile($file,'uploads/'.$random.'',$tmpFile);
    else echo " Error while uploading";
```

Comment: sanoj the function works, a zip file is created with the filename but i doesnt have any contents in it (ie) the zip file created is empty

Comment: @Yesh try now made some changes

Comment: the below answer worked for me... but i cant select files from other directories :/